# Spring Boot - Apache Camel Filter unable to see if finished checking

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

Is there a way in Spring boot Apache camel to know if the input failed to meet the requirement in a `.filter()`?

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off

        from("file://data/inputdir")
        .log("Checking ${file:name}")
        .filter(simple("${file:ext} == 'jpg'"))
                .to("file://data/outputidr/valid")
        .log("Processed in JPG! ${file:name}")
        .end()
        .filter(simple("${file:ext} == 'txt'"))
                .to("file://data/outputidr/validtxt")
        .log("Processed in TXT! ${file:name}")
        .end()
        // @formatter:on

    }
```

I don't know if there is any method available to see if the `.filter()` is already done checking. I want to add in the end something like `.log("${file:name} is not processed");`

Comment: I'm not really sure, but you might want to look into the `peek()` function. But it's use case is more for debugging intended. [peek() tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-peek-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign to a variable of filter result there is a basic example which I write you need change ${body} as ${file:name}

```
from("timer:hello?repeatCount=1")
                .setBody(constant("helloworld"))
                .filter(simple("${body} == 'helloworld1'")).statusPropertyName("anyVariable")
                .log("do something")
                .end()
                .log("process status of '${body}' ${exchangeProperty.anyVariable}");
```

output is

```
 (Camel (camel-15) thread #11 - timer://hello) process status of 'helloworld' false
```